Can a user submit requests to wp-admin/admin.php without logging in?
I have a site that has a malicious link being injected into it which causes every page of the site to be clickable and go to random sites. The script is being injected through the WPCode plugin which has an area in the admin panel to add scripts to the header area. Before removing the plugin, I wanted to figure out how it was being done.
I set up some temporary logging in the wp-admin/admin.php file since the plugin's admin page submits a POST request there. I was able to catch the request of the malicious script being injected along with all of the $_SERVER parameters and the currently logged in user.
The problem is that the user that it was done under hasn't been logged into in about a year according to the admin screen "last logged in" date. The same date shows in the Sucuri plugin's login security area. I don't see any login activity for this user at all.
Is it possible for a user to be submitting requests to wp-admin/admin.php without actually logging in? Or is it more likely that they are logging in as that user somehow and then deleting the login record?

No, this is a red herring that has nothing to do with the problem, likely from a misunderstanding of what WP user login sessions are tracking.
The TLDR: It's probably because they logged out.

The problem is that the user that it was done under hasn't been logged into in about a year according to the admin screen "last logged in" date. The same date shows in the Sucuri plugin's login security area. I don't see any login activity for this user at all.

Not necessarily, WP user login sessions aren't tracking when they last logged in, they're tracking when that specific login session that is still active last logged in. Newer sessions that have ended don't appear here as they've been cleaned up
But keep in mind if they've compromised the site they don't need a login. They could directly modify any of the data you're looking at, or bypass WordPress entirely. If you've identified how they got in you need to close that as soon as possible. Analysis can happen afterwards.

Is it possible for a user to be submitting requests to wp-admin/admin.php without actually logging in?

Normally no, unless new additional PHP code had been introduced to explicitly allow it, it would redirect to a login page. A quick read of admin.php reveals an auth_redirect call near the top.
However by your own admission the site is already compromised so all of that goes out the window since the attacker could have modified files, or executed their own code, and you've already identified malicious code in a code snippet plugin!

Or is it more likely that they are logging in as that user somehow and then deleting the login record?

WordPress does not keep login records!
WordPress Sessions Are Not What You Think They Are
WordPress keeps track of active login sessions. E.g if you login on a phone, then login on a tablet, 2 sessions are tracked. This is so that you can force all devices to log out from the dashboard and invalidate those login sessions.
What they are not, is a record of when people logged in because of the simple fact that logging out destroys a session and removes it from the database.
If I login then logout there is no trace of that session. This means I could log in today then log out, and as long as I never use this machine again I could login as many times as I want on another device and you would never know, as long as I clicked logout.

In general though, wether WordPress normally does or doesn't allow these requests is irrelevant, your site has compromised code that can change it to whatever the attackers want. Removing that malicious code is the number 1 priority.
Also if you could make direct requests to admin.php and bypass authentication/login then that'd be a massive security hole for almost half the internet, the kind of news that would make it into printed newspapers with high profile targets hacked.

Thank you for this information. The reason I ask is because the Sucuri Security WordPress plugin has a whole "Last Logins" area that keeps audit logs of all login attempts, and there's seemingly no activity from this user since 2023 despite my logging showing that user being the one that made the request for the malicious script injection. I removed the script and the user in question that keeps re-injecting the script, but I suppose I should look for modified server files at this point.

without knowing how you've identified that user as the one that did this there's no way to be sure, but that's a separate question. You can't bypass login to perform administrative actions by going directly to admin.php in WordPress
